# How to interpret a theorem stating that orbits are "uniform on average"

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory

I am reading through [these](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edcheragh/Teaching/2015-F-DS-MPE.pdf) notes: [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dcheragh/Teaching/2015-F-DS-MPE.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Edcheragh/Teaching/2015-F-DS-MPE.pdf)

There is a theorem (Theorem 1 under the section Distribution of Orbits) saying the following: [image]

Here $R_{\alpha}^k (x)$ is the $k_{th}$ iteration of the rotation by $\alpha$ map: $R_\alpha(x) = x+\alpha \ (\text{mod} \ 1)$

### Question:

There is a comment just above this theorem saying

> The distribution of
> the orbit is “uniform” on average.

Does this mean that the distributions of orbits on subsets of the circle are also uniform i.e. that if we fix some set $E$ on the circle and wait for the orbit to enter $E$, it has equal probability of landing anywhere in $E$?

Answer (score 0):

If the set $E$ has positive measure, yes.